# ECMAScript code execution order

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I know that ECMAScript does not guarantee the ordering of object properties, even if they happen to be ordered in most implementations.

E.g. there's no guarantee that doing something like `for (var k in obj) ...` will iterate over values of `k` in the order they were added to `obj`.

Because of the unordered nature of objects, I wonder if the following code segment is guaranteed to run in the expected order?

```
var n = 1;
var obj = {
    one: n++,
    two: n++,
    three: n++,
    four: n++
    // ...
};
```

Does ECMAScript guarantee that the properties of `obj` will have their expected values? Or is it possible for this code to execute in an unexpected order, due to the potential unexpected ordering of object properties?

A link to the spec would be great!

Comment: @Barmar nice find, i wouldn't have remembered that one

Comment: @Bergi Wasn't me, it was google: "javascript order of execution object literal"